# Error when login to Gmail with Imap client using Gmail API C#

Tags: c#, api, gmail, gmail-api, gmail-imap

im working on a project that need to access Gmail using Gmail API .
but i keep getting this error when trying to login Imap:

{"status":"400","schemes":"Bearer","scope":"https://mail.google.com/"}

i sew here [OAuth 2 SASL string error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17700114/oauth-2-sasl-string-error) ,that someone asked about this issue and said that it solved by puting the right token scope 
in my case it didnt work , the error is still popping .

```
    static string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly };
    static string ApplicationName = "Gmail API .NET Quickstart";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream =
        new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read))
        {
          string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/gmail-dotnet-quickstart.json");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, Scopes, "Sapir", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }

        // Create Gmail API service.
        var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

        // Define parameters of request.
        UsersResource.LabelsResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.Labels.List("me");


        credential.Token.Scope = "https://mail.google.com/";

        ImapClient ic = new ImapClient("imap.gmail.com","astechnetivot@gmail.com", credential.Token.AccessToken,AuthMethods.SaslOAuth, 993, true);

        ic.SelectMailbox("INBOX");
        Console.WriteLine(ic.GetMessageCount());
        MailMessage[] mm = ic.GetMessages(0, 1);
        foreach (MailMessage m in mm)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Subject + " " + m.Date.ToString());
        }
        ic.Dispose();
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Error message seems to happen when you use an *expired access token*, check your access token and make sure that it is not expired. Here's a related issue having status 400: [Gmail XOAUTH 2.0, IMAP AUTHENTICATE returns "status":"400"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32954851/gmail-xoauth-2-0-imap-authenticate-returns-status400)